# Matlab Stateflow - after() function on transition not working

Tags: matlab, stateflow

In my Stateflow model the after() function is not working. If i put for examle after(10,sec) there is no delay in the states, it switches directly from on to the next. I use a Pulse Generator as an eternal clock for Stateflow with following values:

[image]

Could this be a reason for that behavior? Are there other related setting?

Answer (score 0):

The `after` condition says to do something after you have been in a given state for the specified period of time (in your case 10 seconds).  The pulse generator you show is set to have rising and falling signals every 1 second.  So, without seeing more information about your model, the suspicion would be that you are never in a state long enough for the `after` condition to become true.

It would help if you showed more of your model.